# Transforming html into xhtml (valid xml) in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I am trying to load valid html for processing in Scala. Seems like converting to xml would be a good starting point. It looks like very nice code at the somewhat controversial [scala.xml.Xhtml Scala core library](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/xml/Xhtml.scala#L1) for doing  that. Basically it should entail 'fixing up' tags that are valid in html but not valid xml and hence preventing the document from being valid xhtml, and just a bit more. Here is the code from there:

```
def toXhtml(
    x: Node,
    pscope: NamespaceBinding = TopScope,
    sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder,
    stripComments: Boolean = false,
    decodeEntities: Boolean = false,
    preserveWhitespace: Boolean = false,
    minimizeTags: Boolean = true): Unit =
  {
    def decode(er: EntityRef) = XhtmlEntities.entMap.get(er.entityName) match {
      case Some(chr) if chr.toInt >= 128  => sb.append(chr)
      case _                              => er.buildString(sb)
    }
    def shortForm =
      minimizeTags &&
      (x.child == null || x.child.length == 0) &&
      (minimizableElements contains x.label)

    x match {
      case c: Comment                       => if (!stripComments) c buildString sb
      case er: EntityRef if decodeEntities  => decode(er)
      case x: SpecialNode                   => x buildString sb
      case g: Group                         =>
        g.nodes foreach { toXhtml(_, x.scope, sb, stripComments, decodeEntities, preserveWhitespace, minimizeTags) }

      case _  =>
        sb.append('<')
        x.nameToString(sb)
        if (x.attributes ne null) x.attributes.buildString(sb)
        x.scope.buildString(sb, pscope)

        if (shortForm) sb.append(" />")
        else {
          sb.append('>')
          sequenceToXML(x.child, x.scope, sb, stripComments, decodeEntities, preserveWhitespace, minimizeTags)
          sb.append("</")
          x.nameToString(sb)
          sb.append('>')
        }
    }
  }
```

What seems to take some excessive perseverance is finding how to use that function for an existing html document that has been fetched with `scala.io.Source(fromFile)`. The meaning of the `Node` type seems a bit [elusive](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/xml/NodeSeq.scala) in the code base, or I am unsure how to get from the string received from scala.io.Source's `fromFile`, to something that can be fed into the above copied function `toXhtml`.

[The scaladoc for this function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/xml/Xhtml%24.html) doesn't seem to clarify much.

There's also [another related library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.xml.parsing.XhtmlParser) where the scaladoc only has a zillion entries in it.

I'd be very happy if anyone can say how can a raw html string be converted to 'clean' xhtml using this library, and walk through how to deduce that from [the source code](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/xml/Xhtml%24.html), as my Scala is probably not that good I see..

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this since it excels at dealing with messy, real-world HTML. It can also scrub HTML based on a whitelist of allowed tags. An example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.io.Source

object JsoupExample extends App {
  val suspectHtml = Source.fromURL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)").mkString
  val cleanHtml = Jsoup.clean(suspectHtml, Whitelist.basic)
  val doc = Jsoup.parse(cleanHtml)
  doc.select("p").foreach(node => println(node.text))
}
```

Comment: Yep, I was just hoping there'd be a pure Scala solution, where I can quickly understand the code and change it if necessary. I may adopt that Scala function I mentioned as it's so concise... as I feel I have little idea how liberal or original might jsoup be on inputs I haven't seen yet. The scala code is very concise to follow.. only it's input plumbing is a bit dodgy.